# Send item to pubsub node in asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am developing an android chat client app and I'm using asmack for XMPP implementation.
 I was able to make connection to my XMPP server. I need to send chat messages to specific node to which I'm subscribed.
 I use the following code to fetch messages

```
PubSubManager mgr = new PubSubManager(con);
LeafNode node = mgr.getNode("mynode");
node.subscribe(jid) 
Collection<? extends Item> items = node.getItems();
```

How can I send message/chat to this node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either

```
node.send();
```

or

```
node.publish();
```

You can find examples in the [documentation](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html).